# How can I get to this area as a marine in System Shock 2?

Tags: system-shock-2

It is on the **Recreation B** deck as you can see it on the map. I tried going around and I also looked for hidden switches but no luck. I know that as an *OSA* guy you can teleport (although I don't know how it works) but since I'm a *Marine* it is not an option for me.

This section is opened up after a security bot blasts a wall which it is hiding behind.

Little hint?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

It's not possible to get there. If you really want the pistol/ammo lying near the corpse, you'll need the **Kinetic Redirection** PSI power. Marines don't start with it, but it's purchasable with Cyber Modules if you want it that badly. (It's probably not worth it, especially this late in the game.)

Comment: I'm more interested in the loot the body may hold (a message perhaps?). Are you absolutely sure that one can't get there? What is the point of putting a lootable corpse somewhere where the player can't get to?

Comment: I'm certain. The point is atmosphere. And also to taunt you. And maybe an accident? Who knows.